# Intel TBB causes segfault in exception handling (OS X / gcc 7.2)

Tags: c++, gcc, tbb

This correct example causes a segfault in the `std::cout` line with specific compilation parameters:

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  try {
    throw std::runtime_error("BLA");
  } catch (const std::exception& exception) {
    std::cout << exception.what() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

It only occurs when compiling it on OS X with gcc-7.2 and Intel TBB:

```
g++-7 exception.cpp /usr/local/lib/libtbb.dylib
```

Since the OS X version of TBB is built with clang and linked against libc++, I tried building it with g++-7 from the repo. That does not change anything. Also, the order of arguments does not matter.

On Ubuntu, everything is fine.

This feels like a bug somewhere, but I am not sure where. Any ideas on how to work around this or where to file a bug? I also opened up a [thread](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-threading-building-blocks/topic/749200) in the TBB forums.

---

Some more information that might be helpful:

Stacktrace

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
    frame #0: 0x0000000100000da1 a.out`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff5fbff880) at exception.cpp:8
   5      try {
   6        throw std::runtime_error("BLA");
   7      } catch (const std::exception& exception) {
-> 8        std::cout << exception.what() << std::endl;
   9      }
   10   }
```

Versions

```
[:~/tmp] $ g++-7 --version
g++-7 (Homebrew GCC 7.2.0) 7.2.0
[:~/tmp] $ brew info tbb
tbb: stable 2018_U1 (bottled)
[:~/tmp] $ sw_vers -productVersion
10.12.6
```

ASAN

```
ASAN:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==9698==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x000104c03b22 bp 0x7fff5affc940 sp 0x7fff5affc900 T0)
==9698==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==9698==Hint: address points to the zero page.
    #0 0x104c03b21 in main (/Users/markus/tmp/./a.out+0x100000b21)
    #1 0x7fffa9734234 in start (/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib+0x5234)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV (/Users/markus/tmp/./a.out+0x100000b21) in main
==9698==ABORTING
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: Intel people say that this combination of OS and compiler is not supported. I'd still love to find a fix for this, especially since the rest of TBB seems to work.

Comment: The problem is discussing on [the TBB fourm](https://software.intel.com/en-us/comment/1916078)